# delphi MDI form without Tmainmenu

Tags: delphi

I am trying to work with MDI forms without TMainMenu and call Form2 from speedbutton which on Ttoolbar. when Form2(child) maximized , form header and bordericons disappears.
[image]

I  want Form2(child) will be maximized under Ttoolbar and header and border icons are visible
[image]

Comment: That is how MDI works. It must have a main menu on which to display the small buttons for the child windows and to limit the size of the child windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how MDI works. instead of using MDI you can use a TPanel and set it as Parent for child forms, something like this:

```
var
 FChild: TfrmChild;
begin
 FChild := TfrmChild.Create(Self);
 FChild.Parent := pnlMain;
 FChild.Show;
end;
```

...

[image]